# CSS and JS files is not loading in Laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

My application is on the server, and I have tried all the solutions. But my Laravel app is still not loading CSS and JS files in `main.blade.php` when my CSS files are in public/assets_setup/css/style.css.` I even made file changes, but page changes are not showing in inspect, and it's the same.

Below is my main.blade.php file which all links are included.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYbcW.png]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets_setup/css/style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/assets_setup/css/style.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't write public in laravel